# LIBCMTD.lib(wcrt0.obj) LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wmain referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup unresolved externals freeGLUT.dll

Tags: linker-errors, visual-studio-debugging, freeglut

I am using a solution (not my own) in VS2010 developed using freeGLUT, the open source and extended alternative to GLUT (OpenGL's Utility Toolkit). The program compiles and runs the exe while in Release mode just fine, but when trying to debug, I get the following errors:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *wmain referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup  LIBCMTD.lib(wcrt0.obj)  freeglut

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   freeglut.dll    freeglut

I downloaded and referenced all of the lib and include files like README file told me:

```
Installation

Create a folder on your PC which is readable by all users, for example
“C:\Program Files\Common Files\MSVC\freeglut\” on a typical Windows system. Copy
the “lib\” and “include\” folders from this zip archive to that location.

The appropriate freeglut DLL can either be placed in the same folder as your
application, or can be installed in a system-wide folder which appears in your
%PATH% environment variable. Be careful not to mix the 32 bit DLL up with the 64
bit DLL, as they are not interchangeable.


Compiling 32 bit Applications

To create a 32 bit freeglut application, create a new Win32 C++ project in MSVC.
From the “Win32 Application Wizard”, choose a “Windows application”, check the
“Empty project” box, and submit.

You’ll now need to configure the compiler and linker settings. Open up the
project properties, and select “All Configurations” (this is necessary to ensure
our changes are applied for both debug and release builds). Open up the
“general” section under “C/C++”, and configure the “include\” folder you created
above as an “Additional Include Directory”. If you have more than one GLUT
package which contains a “glut.h” file, it’s important to ensure that the
freeglut include folder appears above all other GLUT include folders.

Now open up the “general” section under “Linker”, and configure the “lib\”
folder you created above as an “Additional Library Directory”.


A freeglut
application depends on the import libraries “freeglut.lib” and “opengl32.lib”,
which can be configured under the “Input” section.


However, it shouldn’t be
necessary to explicitly state these dependencies, since the freeglut headers
handle this for you. Now open the “Advanced” section, and enter “mainCRTStartup”
as the “Entry Point” for your application. This is necessary because GLUT
applications use “main” as the application entry point, not “WinMain”—without it
you’ll get an undefined reference when you try to link your application.

That’s all of your project properties configured, so you can now add source
files to your project and build the application. If you want your application to
be compatible with GLUT, you should “#include <GL/glut.h>”. If you want to use
freeglut specific extensions, you should “#include <GL/freeglut.h>” instead.

Don’t forget to either include the freeglut DLL when distributing applications,
or provide your users with some method of obtaining it if they don’t already
have it!
```

Here is a link to the screenshots of the linker settings as I have them now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O67nK.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Properties->Linker->System->SubSytem

Change Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) to Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)

Answer (score 0):

"wmain" is the main entry point for a graphical Windows .exe.

Q: Did you select "Windows application" like the instructions said?

Q: Are you building an .exe (an entire program), or just a .dll?

The linker thinks you're trying to build an .exe, and it wants a "main program" (with "wmain()).

If you're building a .dll, change your Visual Studio "target" to .dll and "Rebuild all".

If you're building an .exe, find the "main module" and make sure it's included in your project.

Comment: Thanks for a response. The solution was made by a company, and licensed for free to developers. It is a Win32 application. I just want to be able to step through and evaluate variables, and I'm guessing that the .dll's are the file type I should use for such a thing, but I've never had to deal with the file types when debugging before.

"$(ProjectName)" is the target, and the target extension is ".dll." Thanks again.